# Make a ListView with Parse data

Tags: listview, parse-platform, android-parsequeryadapter

I tried to add the Parse UI-widget to be able to use the Parse Query Adapter, however it didn't work and I almost messed up my whole app trying.

So, my question is if there are any other ways to create a listView with your data from Parse? I mean, if the Query Adapter was so important, why would they move it so it's not importable anymore, if it's the only way to make listViews?

Comment: Anybody has a clue how to make a listview??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was your problem , I cloned the ParseUI-Widget and I put compile project(':ParseUI-Widget') in dependencies on Buil.Gradle and now I can work with ParseQueryAdapter. I think you can work without Parse adapter, but it is a whole problem.

Sorry my bad english.